# Добавление и удаление класса элемента по клику на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть два дива и кнопка

```
<div id="one" class="hidden"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<button>Click</button>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы по клику на кнопку первый див не имел класс `"hidden"`, а второй наоборот его получил.
Класс `"hidden"` скрывает элемент.
Или может есть какое-то другое более простое решение проблемы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с использованием jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('#one, #two').toggleClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one" class="hidden">One</div>
<div id="two">Two</div>
<button>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

На `JavaScript` с использованием `add` и `remove` методов можно так:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var elementOne = document.getElementById('one');
  var elementTwo = document.getElementById('two');
  
  if (elementOne.classList.contains("hidden")) {
    elementOne.classList.remove("hidden");
    elementTwo.classList.add("hidden");
  } else {
    elementOne.classList.add("hidden");
    elementTwo.classList.remove("hidden");
  }
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="hidden">One</div>
<div id="two">Two</div>
<button>Click</button>
```

Но лучше с использованием `toggle` метода (будет меньше *лапши*):

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('one').classList.toggle("hidden");
  document.getElementById('two').classList.toggle("hidden");
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="hidden">One</div>
<div id="two">Two</div>
<button>Click</button>
```

---

> [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)  является геттером, возвращаемый им объект имеет
> несколько методов и свойство:
>
> - `add(String [,String])` - добавляет элементу указанные классы
> - `remove(String [,String])` - удаляет у элемента указанные классы
> - `item(Number)` - результат аналогичен вызову `сlassList[Number]`
> - `toggle(String [, Boolean])` - если класс у элемента отсутствует - добавляет, иначе - убирает. Когда вторым параметром передано `false` -
>   удаляет указанный класс, а если `true` - добавляет.
> - `contains(String)` - проверяет, есть ли данный класс у элемента (вернет    `true` или `false`)
> - `length` - свойство , которое возвращает количество классов у    элемента.

Comment: Только один раз при нажатии на кнопку что-то происходит.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.getElementById('one').className = '';
  document.getElementById('two').className = 'hidden'
})
```

```html
<div id="one" class="hidden">one</div>
<div id="two">two</div>
<button>Click</button>
```