# Почему не добавляется и не удаляется class элементу?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Сколько уже сижу, не могу понять в чём причина того, почему не работает код. 
Делаю по этому примеру ( https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav ), только через flexbox. Может в js ошибка. Почему-то, когда я нажимаю на тот значок, то стили, которые я задавал раньше, пропадают. Крч, кому не сложно, посмотрите пожалуйста.

```js
function iconMenu() {
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName('topnav')[0];
 if (x.className == "topnav") {
  x.className += "responsive";
 }
 else {
  x.className = "topnav";
 }
}
```

```css
.header, .topnav {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: black;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

.topnav a:hover {
   background-color: #ddd;
   color: black;
}

.topnav a {
 font-size: 20px;
 color: white;
 padding: 10px;
}

#active {
 background-color: green;
}


.topnav .icon {
 flex-grow: 1;
 text-align: right;
 display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="topnav">
   <a href="#" class="hrefs" id="active">Home</a>
   <a href="#" class="hrefs">News</a>
   <a href="#" class="hrefs">Contacts</a>
   <a href="#" class="hrefs">About</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="iconMenu()">&#9776;</a>
  </div>
 </header>
```

[image: После нажатия]

[image: Так есть до нажатия]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вам уже дали ответ, проблема в отсутствующем пробеле в строке `x.className += "responsive";` перед именем класса, если его нет, то получится имя слепленное из двух частей `"topnavresponsive"`.

Но я бы рекомендовал редактировать классы элемента через [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), вот ссылка на ответ, где это расписано подробнее: [Добавление и удаление класса элемента по клику на кнопку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/658494/189339). На мой взгляд так намного удобнее это делать. Ну и модификация вашего кода под `classList` (кстати, у `.topnav .icon` я закомментировал свойство `display: none;`, чтобы элемент отображался и срабатывала функция `iconMenu()`):

```js
function iconMenu() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('topnav')[0];
  console.log('before: ' + x.classList);
  if (x.classList.contains("responsive")) {
    x.classList.remove("responsive");
  } else {
    x.classList.add("responsive");
  }
  console.log('after: ' + x.classList);
}
```

```css
.header,
.topnav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

#active {
  background-color: green;
}

.topnav .icon {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: right;
  /* display: none; */
  /* Убрал этот стиль, чтобы отображался значек */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">
  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="#" class="hrefs" id="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="hrefs">News</a>
    <a href="#" class="hrefs">Contacts</a>
    <a href="#" class="hrefs">About</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="iconMenu();">&#9776;</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Функция уже работает, но по прежнему результата нету, того что получается в примере на w3school (при ресайзе оно всё равно не работает).
Я, кстати, пытался сделать через classList :)
Я только изучил JS и сейчас пытаюсь применить на практике.
Но Вы мне очень помогли, спасибо

Comment: @AndrewYaremchuk всегда пожалуйста.  Кажется, что пример немного кривой на w3school :)

Comment: Так как тут нету ЛС, то задам здесь вопрос, ибо знакомых из IT нету, а я вижу Вы разбираетесь.
После того как изучил JavaScript стоит ли сразу изучать JQuery? И вообще стоит ли его изучать, или лучше начать изучать из React?

Comment: @AndrewYaremchuk скажу вам основываясь на своем опыте, что jQuery встречается практически повсеместно, но там нет ничего сложного, можно сразу совместно с React изучать.  Просто по сути jQuery - это JavaScript библиотека, которая  упрощает работу с элементами DOM, обращение к атрибутам и содержимому. Поэтому - учите сразу все, лишним оно точно не будет! :)

Answer (score 1):

Потому, что класс строка , и Вы к строке topnav конкатенируйте строку responsive без пробела, и в классе выходит topnavresponsive, и потому пропадают стили и от topnav и responsive не добавляет ничего нового!

```js
function iconMenu() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('topnav')[0];
  if (x.className == " topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = " topnav";
  }
  console.log(x)
}
```

```css
.header,
.topnav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

#active {
  background-color: green;
}

.topnav .icon {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: right;
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="#" class="hrefs" id="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="hrefs">News</a>
    <a href="#" class="hrefs">Contacts</a>
    <a href="#" class="hrefs">About</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="iconMenu()">&#9776;</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Вот я дебил :С 
Спасибо огромное )

Comment: Да все нормально, сам так бывало туплю, а бывали ситуации, что просто писал в другом файле стили и они не применялись "почему-то", так бывало) Рад был помочь, успехов!

Comment: Ахах, жиза.
И Вам удачки )